# Can you apply metamagic on Wish spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, metamagic, wish

Can you apply metamagic on the *Wish* spell? For example using Twinned Spell on *Otto's Irresistible Dance* cast through *Wish*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Yes

This is specifically addressed in the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=5):

> **Can my sorcerer use Twinned Spell on a spell duplicated by the casting of a *wish* spell? And if so, how many sorcery points does it cost?** Yes, you can. It costs the number of sorcery points appropriate for the level of the spell you’re duplicating.